# Flex and full UTF-8 Support?

Tags: utf-8, flexbuilder

Doing some software review for a RIA project - I was hoping to use Flex but need to make sure it has full UTF-8 support - I'm talking all fonts for all languages - everything from English, to Finish, to Russian, to Japanese to Thai to Sanskrit...

I haven't worked with Flash/Flex/ActionScript in years - but I seem to remember it's up to the font you embed into the movie - so if you have, say MS Arial UniCode that has the full character set you simply include in the movie and the support is there to display the characters?  Is this right?

Also including that level of character support(that large a font) -how much does that bloat the application?

Any insight would be helpful as I am still in the information gather stage.
Other software suggestions would also be appreciated.

Thanks
JD

Answer (score 0):

If you use ActionScript 3 (and you should), all strings are Unicode.
And if you use the newer text components (Flash 10) then the text engine supports complex scripts (including Russia, Japanese, and Indic scripts).

All you would have to do is make sure you have the right fonts. You might embed your own (with the mandatory bloat that you can't avoid if you embed a 30 MB Chinese font :-)
In practice you will probably just use the system fonts.
Among others because there are no free and good quality Chinese/Japanese fonts. And you have not right to embed the font without the proper licensing (and the prices are not low :-)